# Displaying coupon error messages on front end commerce 4

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, cart, plugin-craftcommerce4

I have read in the Commerce documentation that natively, commerce doesn't display any errors when a false coupon is being entered. Did I understand the docs correctly or is there any why to achieve that? Or any plugin that deals with that?

Right now if an invalid/expired coupon is being submitted in the checkout, nothing happens and that can be confusing...

Any hint will be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a coupon triggers an error, that error is part of the cart element. It's accessed as `couponCode`
This is from a Craft 3 project (4 i believe is same):

```
 {% set firstCouponCodeNotice = cart.getFirstNotice(null, 'couponCode') %}
 {% if firstCouponCodeNotice %}
      <div class="errors">
          {{ firstCouponCodeNotice }}
      </div>
  {% endif %}
```

Edit: documentation link added

https://craftcms.com/docs/commerce/4.x/orders-carts.html#order-notices

If you want one snippet to handle both carts and orders...

```
{% set model = cart is defined ? cart : order is defined ? order : NULL %}
{% if model %}
    {% set firstCouponCodeNotice = model.getFirstNotice(null, 'couponCode') %}
    {% if firstCouponCodeNotice %}
         <div class="errors">
             {{ firstCouponCodeNotice }}
         </div>
     {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: For context, there's some discussion about how this works here: https://github.com/craftcms/commerce/issues/2491 - personally I continue to think the design of this behaviour is far from ideal.